# Anchoring widgets in kivy 1.9.0 RelativeLayout

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I have created a RelativeLayout subclass that positions its children in a grid by supplying them positions in the code (Python, not kv file). It works, but items are placed some 25 pixels to the upper-right from the position of layout itself, as shown by the canvas block. Python code for Layout subclass:

```
class RLMapWidget(RelativeLayout):

    def __init__(self, map=None, **kwargs):
        super(FloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        #  Connecting to map, factories and other objects this class should know about
        self.tile_factory = TileWidgetFactory()
        self.map = map
        #  Initializing tile widgets for BG layer and adding them as children
        for x in range(self.map.size[0]):
            for y in range(self.map.size[1]):
                tile_widget = self.tile_factory.create_tile_widget(self.map.get_item(layer='bg',
                                                                                    location=(x, y)))
                # tile_widget.pos = (50*x, 50*y)
                tile_widget.pos = self._get_screen_pos((x, y))
                self.add_widget(tile_widget)
        #  Initializing widgets for actor layers
        for x in range(self.map.size[0]):
            for y in range(self.map.size[1]):
                if self.map.has_item(layer='actors', location=(x, y)):
                    actor_widget = self.tile_factory.create_actor_widget(self.map.get_item(layer='actors',
                                 displayed                                                          location=(x, y)))
                    actor_widget.pos=(50*x, 50*y)
                    self.add_widget(actor_widget)
        #  Map background canvas. Used solely to test positioning
        with self.canvas.before:
            Color(0, 0, 1, 1)
            self.rect = Rectangle(size = self.size, pos=self.pos)
            self.bind(pos=self.update_rect, size=self.update_rect)
        #  Initializing keyboard bindings and key lists
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_key_down)
        #  The list of keys that will not be ignored by on_key_down
        self.used_keys=['w', 'a', 's', 'd']

    def redraw_actors(self):
        for actor in self.map.actors:
            actor.widget.pos = self._get_screen_pos(actor.location)

    def _get_screen_pos(self, location):
        """
        Return screen coordinates (in pixels) for a given location
        :param location: int tuple
        :return: int tuple
        """
        return (location[0]*50, location[1]*50)

    #  Keyboard-related methods

    def _on_key_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        """
        Process keyboard event and make a turn, if necessary
        :param keyboard:
        :param keycode:
        :param text:
        :param modifiers:
        :return:
        """
        if keycode[1] in self.used_keys:
            self.map.process_turn(keycode)
            self.redraw_actors()

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_key_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def update_rect(self, pos, size):
        self.rect.pos = self.pos
        self.rect.size = self.size


class CampApp(App):

    def build(self):
        root = FloatLayout()
        map_factory = MapFactory()
        map = map_factory.create_test_map()
        map_widget = RLMapWidget(map=map,
                                 size=(map.size[0]*50, map.size[1]*50),
                                 size_hint=(None, None))
        root.add_widget(map_widget)
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    CampApp().run()
```

Factory class that makes tiles:

```
class TileWidgetFactory(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def create_tile_widget(self, tile):
        tile.widget = Image(source=tile.image_source,
                            size_hint=(None, None))
        return tile.widget

    def create_actor_widget(self, actor):
        actor.widget = Image(source='Tmp_frame_black.png',
                             size_hint=(None, None))
        return actor.widget
```

Comment: unrelated but you may consider using `staticmethod` for the methods in `TileWidgetFactory`

Comment: Probably not: I plan to use attributes of a factory later, so that it'll know exactly what kind of widgets are supposed to be generated (size, level-specific effects and such).

Comment: I'll be quiet then, it is just a pet peeve of mine when you have to do something like `MyClass.should_be_static(None,my_value)` to make it work properly because it isn't labeled as a staticmethod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, solved it myself. It turns out that if I supply the size to child widgets in factory, they are positioned properly. Although it solves the problem I have, I'd still be grateful if someone can explain where this quirk does come from.